# GitHub SSH key on a USB drive

Tags: github, ssh, ssh-keys, usb-drive, nixos

I'm curious if I can put a GitHub SSH key on a USB flash drive as a singular key and remove the other SSH keys from my GitHub. I've found one source, but it doesn't necessarily specify that it's for GH, [here](https://blog.costan.ro/post/2022-03-15-ssh-keys-on-usb/).

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

I have yet to experiment, just reading articles/watching YouTube videos to try and get a grasp on it.

Comment: Private keys are just files so... yes? You might be interested in [How to tell git which private key to use?](https://superuser.com/q/232373/81031)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are using a `~/.ssh/config` file which points where your SSH key is, you can put said key pair wherever you want.

```
Host gh
  Hostname github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile /mnt/usb-device/myKey
```

In your case, a `nix copy --to file:///mnt/usb-device /path/to/key` would be needed first.
However, the tutorial you are referring to is more about copying the key on an *encrypted* USB stick. Which might be a bit redundant, considering NixOS can be installed with [Full Disk Encryption](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Full_Disk_Encryption) already.